# Selecting rows referenced by another table in Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod

Suppose I have the following Yesod (Database.Persist) database schema:

```
File
   path Text

Tag
   name Text

FileTag
   file FileId
   tag TagId
   UniqueFileTag file tag
```

What is the most convenient way in Yesod to select File records that are referenced by a given Tag record? Do I need to resort to custom SQL? I'm using PostgreSQL as the database backend.

Answer (score 3):

You can use custom SQL to solve this problem; I don't think Persistent offers a different solution, since it's not an ORM because it has to support non-relational backends like MongoDB.

You can implement a basic join like this:

```
let tagFileStatement =
  Text.concat
  [ "SELECT ?? "
  , "FROM  file,     file_tag "
  , "WHERE file.id = file_tag.file "
  , "AND   ?       = file_tag.tag"
  ]
files <- runDB $ rawSql tagFileStatement
         [toPersistValue theTagIdThatYouWantToLookupFilesFor]
files :: [Entity File]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the code snippet. I'll try to see if I can automate writing these kind of queries.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module for handling one-to-many relationships, either as [application-level joins](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/persistent/1.0.0/doc/html/Database-Persist-Query-Join.html) or as [a proper SQL join](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/persistent/1.0.0/doc/html/Database-Persist-Query-Join-Sql.html). These modules probably count as the most poorly documented aspect in the entire Yesod project, unfortunately. Longer term, we're hoping to improve the state of more complex SQL queries, but we don't have any actual code to show for this right now.

There are a few threads on the Yesod mailing list covering how to use these, here's one thread that popped up: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/yesodweb/a4EAvPS8wFA/ClPuS94TRFwJ%5B1-25%5D . We really need to either improve the Haddocks or write a wiki page detailing the behavior better.

Comment: Doh, you're absolutely correct, my mistake. I misread the question.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at those posts. My Haskell skills are not yet at the level that I can figure out how to use the library by just staring at the type signatures. :)

Comment: For your described use case, I think @dflemstr's answer is the best approach. If you end up needing one-to-many, you can try the join modules, but it likely won't help you here.